# How can we combine two lists in lightning controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am using two lists in lightning controller.i want to combine those two lists.How can we achieve it?

i am using below lists.

```
    var serchnotnull = component.get("v.secondselectedRowsList");
    var serch = component.get("v.selectedRowsList");
```

now i want to push these two list variables data to third list variable.How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `var concatArray = serchnotnull.concat(serch)`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Array.prototype.push.apply?

```
var serchnotnull = component.get("v.secondselectedRowsList");
var serch = component.get("v.selectedRowsList");
Array.prototype.push.apply(serchnotnull, serch);
console.log(serchnotnull); //cOntains serchnotnull and serch elements
```

Src: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35658464/what-is-the-equivalent-of-java-collection-addall-for-javascript-arrays/35658514